# logstash not pushing logs to AWS Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to push my logs from logstash to elasticsearch but its failing. here is my logstash.conf file :

```
input {
            file {
                    path => "D:/shweta/ELK_poc/test3.txt"
                    start_position => "beginning"
                    sincedb_path => "NUL"
                    ignore_older => 0
                }}

    output {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => [ "https://search-test-domain2-2msy6ufh2vl2ztfulhrtoat6hu.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com" ]
            index => "testindex4-5july"
            document_type => "test-file"
        }
    }
```

The ES endpoint that i have provided in hosts is open , so there should not be an access isssue, but it still gives following error:

```
_[2018-07-05T13:59:05,753][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>https://search-test-domain2-2msy6ufh2vl2ztfulhrtoat6hu.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com:9200/, :path=>"/"}_
_[2018-07-05T13:59:05,769][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"https://search-test-domain2-2msy6ufh2vl2ztfulhrtoat6hu.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [https://search-test-domain2-2msy6ufh2vl2ztfulhrtoat6hu.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server (search-test-domain2-2msy6ufh2vl2ztfulhrtoat6hu.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com)"}_
```

I am stuck here. But when i downloaded ES and installed it in my machine and ran it locally , replacing hosts with: `hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]` ,in output , it worked all good pushing data to local es:

I tried a lot of ways but not able to resolve the issue , can anyone please help. I don't want to give localhost but AWS ES domain endpoint. Any hints or leads will be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance
Shweta

Comment: why haven't you provided port number in your `hosts` ? i.e `9200`?

Comment: @SufiyanGhori AWS ES works on port 443 (SSL), so that's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you simply need to explicitly add the port 443 and it will work. I think the `elasticsearch` output plugin [automatically uses port 9200](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/master/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb#L232-L237) if no port is explicitly given.

```
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "https://search-test-domain2-2msy6ufh2vl2ztfulhrtoat6hu.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com:443" ]
        index => "testindex4-5july"
        document_type => "test-file"
    }
```

An alternative would be to not add the port but specify `ssl => true` as depicted in the [official AWS ES docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-kibana.html)

```
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "https://search-test-domain2-2msy6ufh2vl2ztfulhrtoat6hu.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com" ]
        index => "testindex4-5july"
        document_type => "test-file"
        ssl => true
    }
```

Comment: can we ingest data into amazon ES instance from a machine outside AWS? I'm facing a similar issue when the source of ingestion is not an EC2 instance. But I'm able to query the indices.